# How to know when a group of images are loaded from web?

Tags: c#, image, events, windows-8

I have a view that fetches between 1 and 5 images (depending on the data received from server) into a `StackPanel`, and today they simply pop into view whenever they are downloaded (in any random order). I'd like to hide all images until they all are available for rendering (i.e. when they all are loaded from the web and ready to display).

Now, every Image has a `Loaded`-event which I could listen for. However, keeping track of an array of true / false values and constantly polling this sounds like a bad idea. Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Let's say you show your many different images like this:

```
<Grid Background="Black">
    <StackPanel x:Name="ImageContainer" Opacity="0" Width="100">
        <Image Loaded="Image_Loaded_1" Source="http://www.hdwallpaperspk.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/1600x1200_hd_wallpaper_177.jpg" />
        <Image Loaded="Image_Loaded_1" Source="http://www.hdwallpaperspk.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/nature-wallpaper-hd1.jpg" />
        <Image Loaded="Image_Loaded_1" Source="http://hidefwalls.com/wp-content/g/hd-2/hd-wallpaper-30.jpg" />
        <Image Loaded="Image_Loaded_1" Source="http://beautifulcoolwallpapers.files.wordpress.com/2011/09/red-tree-wallpaper-hd.jpg" />
        <Image Loaded="Image_Loaded_1" Source="http://hidefwalls.com/wp-content/g/hd-2/at-the-beach-hd-wallpaper-1920x1200.jpg" />
        <Image Loaded="Image_Loaded_1" Source="http://freedomwallpaper.com/wallpaper/funky-wallpaper-hd.jpg" />
        <Image Loaded="Image_Loaded_1" Source="http://walfast.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/wallpaper-hd.jpg" />
        <Image Loaded="Image_Loaded_1" Source="http://www.hdwallpaperspk.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/hd-wallpaper-6-o-u-ibackgroundz-com_.jpg" />
        <Image Loaded="Image_Loaded_1" Source="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-dcgYv-SFEu0/TZVuveCkq1I/AAAAAAAAI2A/vK0PXUJ8aKw/s1600/tiger_wallpapers_hd_Bengal_Tiger_hd_wallpaper.jpg" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Then you can hide them until they are all loaded like this:

```
object m_ImagesLock = new object();
private List<Image> m_ImagesLoading = new List<Image>();

private void Image_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    lock (m_ImagesLock)
    {
        var _Image = sender as Image;
        m_ImagesLoading.Add(_Image);
        var _Action = new Action(() =>
        {
            m_ImagesLoading.Remove(_Image);
            ImageContainer.Opacity = m_ImagesLoading.Any() ? 0 : 1;
        });
        _Image.ImageOpened += (s, arg) => _Action();
        _Image.ImageFailed += (s, arg) => _Action();
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this did exactly what I wanted.